# MOSFET Mode determination

Tags: mosfet

I am looking into using a MOSFET in the ohmic region at a given VGS. However I am having trouble interpreting the typical I-V curve of a MOSFET.

Surely the y-axis parameter, i.e. the drain current, is generally the parameter that is changed by the x-axis parameter. But in this case, surely it is the y-axis parameter that is changing the x-axis parameter. Or to ask it another way, how can I accurately model the VDS change in a circuit?

[image]

Comment: The FET is a 3-terminal component; that 3rd lead provides a way to chose the vertical-horizontal curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the current through a resistor determine the voltage across it? Or does the voltage across the resistor determine its current? Both models are equally true, and either model could be more useful for analyzing a circuit, depending what is connected to the resistor.

One way to look at the MOSFET is that its drain-source channel is a nonlinear resistor, with an I-V curve determined by the gate-source voltage. And like any other resistor, in some cases you might want to use the voltage to determine the current; and other times you might want to use the current to determine the voltage.

It just happens that we conventionally graph this characteristic with the voltage on the x-axis (usually associated with the independent variable) and the current on the y-axis (usually associated with a dependent variable). Either way (if you included channel length modulation and parasitic resistances in your model) there would be a 1-to-1 relationship between voltage and current, and you can use the graph to find either one, given the other.

Comment: ahh okay. So the I-V graph doesn't impose the standard x and y-axis convention as  a strict rule?

Comment: @Hart22, how could a graph do any such thing?